# Google App Engine 500 Error, but why?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting the following error in App Engine after I deployed it. Does anybody know the reason? It's causing an error page sometimes. It seems simplejson is the cause...

According to http://code.google.com/status/appengine/ everyting should be working accordingly.

```
  09-20 11:03AM 56.027 / 500 55902ms 240cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; nl-nl) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5,gzip(gfe)
 - - [20/Sep/2010:11:04:51 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; nl-nl) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5,gzip(gfe)" "" ms=55903 cpu_ms=240 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.006723 loading_request=1 pending_ms=1266
E 09-20 11:04AM 51.915
<class 'google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError'>: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps//7.344918194765199957/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from logic import home, program, image, searchhandler, twitter, sitemap, feed
  File "/base/data/home/apps/7.344918194765199957/logic/home.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils import simplejson
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/utils/simplejson/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from django.utils.simplejson.decoder import JSONDecoder
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/utils/simplejson/decoder.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.utils.simplejson.scanner import Scanner, pattern
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/utils/simplejson/scanner.py", line 3, in <module>
    """
I 09-20 11:04AM 51.924
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

This is the error that the page will show:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

It seems this is not the only error causing the 500 error. Because most of the time this seems to be the cause:

```
09-20 11:37AM 18.229 /ohohcherso.html 500 11007ms 0cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.62 Safari/534.3,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)
94.209.194.233 - sammiestoel [20/Sep/2010:11:37:29 -0700] "GET /ohohcherso.html HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "http://www.tweetstream.nl/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.62 Safari/534.3,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)" "www.tweetstream.nl" ms=11008 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000148
W 09-20 11:37AM 29.237
Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request. This may happen sporadically when the App Engine serving cluster is under unexpectedly high or uneven load. If you see this message frequently, please contact the App Engine team.
```

Comment: The real error seems to be missing. There should be 2 lines after the `File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/utils/simplejson/scanner.py", line 3, in <module>` with the real error. Or a line just above the `Traceback`

Comment: Edited the question with full error code. Sorry..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
<class 'google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError'>
```

Your page is too slow, it should load within 30 seconds. Otherwise the App Engine will kill it.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer

Comment: AH thanks for that link, I didn't know that. But could you also check my last error? That error is being caused the whole time now..

Comment: @Sam S: that's quite a common error after publishing your app from my experience. It can take a couple of minutes before the app is completely running so the first time you just have to wait a bit.

Comment: Ok I will also look into optimalizations. I should be able to fix DeadlineExceededError with optimlization right? Thanks for your answer, will mark it as accepted if no better answers arrive ;)

Comment: @Sam S: Yes, it's perfectly possible to run pages within that time. Might I suggest you try the Kay framework instead? It's based on Django with some App Engine specific fixes: http://code.google.com/p/kay-framework/

Comment: I'm also going through this problem currently... I use the background thread to ssh to ec2: cmd = "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -i {0} ubuntu@{1} \"pwd\"".format(keyfile, ip) success = os.system(cmd). Since it takes some time to finish the connection, it's just killed after a while with the "GET /_ah/background HTTP/1.1" 500 error. But I really need to do the ssh..... How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the real problem was there was a """ in the file as some comments, which created the 500 error. The app is working smooth now. I'm happy I found it at last.

So if you get this error first check if you made comments in a bad way!